# How to change the number format of the column that a range is, using xlwings pyhton

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have a range and I would like to change the number format of the whole column.

I am trying the following but it doesn't change anything:

```
myRange.columns.number_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The columns property hasn't been properly implemented in xlwings as of 0.22.0, so the easiest way to refer to a column is like this:

```
xw.Book(...).sheets[0].range('A:A').number_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm'
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Maybe was not clear but my problem was to get the column object from the range and then apply number formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Where the xlwings API stops, you can always switch to the full blown [Microsoft API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)):

```
myRange.api.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm'
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit nasty solution but did the job:

```
myRange.sheet.book.sheets[myRange.sheet.name].range(chr(ord('@')+myRange.column)+":"+chr(ord('@')+myRange.column)).number_format = '@'
```